# Dynamic Menu Grid in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

I want to build a Web page (in Asp.Net) containing a Dynamic Menu where the user can Move the Icons or the Menu contents, like a grid menu in android for example...
What should I use? CSS, Javascript, HTML5 or JQuery, anything to start with.
All what I want is a Large icons Menu that icons can be Moved dynamically...

Thanks all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty broad question, but you definitely will need Javascript/jQuery to get this done.
I would look into the jQuery UI library and especially into http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ for draggable elements.

Since you're aiming for an Asp.Net site with, I'm assuming, dynamic content to feed the menu; I would start by building a static version of the kind of menu you want, using Html, CSS and jQuery. Once you get that part working right, you can look into building an Asp.NET user control or a configurable custom control that will render the entire html/JS/css markup based on dynamic content.